# global is not defined in jest test file

Tags: node.js, jestjs

`global` variable in JS is not able to access in jest test files, also not able to change the values which are already defined in global.

the work around I have did is as follow:

```
require('./../../../../bin/global');

describe('gloablAccessMethod', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        // jest.spyOn(regionConfig,'global.regionConfig').mockImplementation(() => ({
        //     'ENABLE_CONFIG' : false
        // }));
        global.regionConfig.ENABLE_CONFIG = false;
    });

    const PHONE_PREFIX_SG = 65;
    it('should access mock global variables', () =>{
      //some sample tests
    });
});
```

jest configuration

````
    "jest": {
        "timers": "fake",
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "setupFiles": [
            "./.jest/setEnv.js"
        ],
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
            "./.jest/setup.js"
        ],
        "coverageReporters": [
            "text",
            "cobertura"
        ],
        "collectCoverage": true,
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
        ]
    },```
````

Comment: Show the `jest.config.js` and the jest command you execute.

Comment: i updated my jest config